# Error reading values from dynamically created table rows in Android

Tags: android, tablerow

So I have a couple of dynamically created tablerows.Each TableRow has a couple of Textviews.I have a button that on clicked should get all the values of the second and third textviews in each Tablerow in the Table. I have tried to do this using the code below

```
          mSubmitOrders.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mTable.getChildCount()>1){
                for(int i = 0; i < mTable.getChildCount(); i++){

                    TableRow tr =  (TableRow)mTable.getChildAt(i);
                    TextView code = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(1);
                    TextView quantity = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(2);

                    String Scode = code.getText().toString();
                    Log.i("TAG", Scode);
                    String Squantity = quantity.getText().toString();
                    Log.i("TAG", Squantity);


            }   
            }
```

But I get the below errors (Logcat below). Assistance required

```
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495): java.lang.ClassCastException:       android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at com.symetry.myitprovider.ui.actual$4.onClick(actual.java:173)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3131)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12035)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
10-22 09:00:16.345: E/AndroidRuntime(4495):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SOLVED:
After getting help from at @zacck here is how i finally solved it:

```
                 for(int i = 0; i < mTable.getChildCount(); i++){
                    TableRow tr = (TableRow) mTable.getChildAt(i);

                    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)tr.getChildAt(1);
                    LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout)tr.getChildAt(2);



                    TextView code = (TextView)l1.getChildAt(0);
                    sCode = code.getText().toString();
                    Log.v("Inserted---->", sCode);
                    codeA[i]=sCode;


                    TextView quantity = (TextView)l2.getChildAt(0);
                    sQuantity = quantity.getText().toString();
                    Log.v("Inserted--->", sQuantity);
                    quantityA[i]=sQuantity;

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

before that u have to tag the individual view of the rows by `setTag(position)`or u can use any unique value as parameter. Then u can get the views content by the reference of  `getTag()`.

Comment: The tablerows  are dynamically created inside the TableLayout...so when you say i use setTag(position) i assume that position is an int value to uniquely identify a tablerow? How would I do this?

Comment: for each row u can set the tag as row.setTag("row NO"); then for each view within that row set tag as..                                for(int i=0;i<no_of_ view;i++){          "urview".setTag(row.getTag+","+i);}